# Project vertices to middle plane

Tags: vertices, faces, project

I have two rectangular profiles that face each other at an angle (see image). Now I want to create a middle plane in between those faces with the outer vertices on the continuation of those profiles. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with the *TinyCAD* addon:

- Extend the edges along their axis with *GG + C*:

[image]

- Activate the *TinyCAD* addon, select all and right click > *TinyCAD > XALL*:

[image]

- Clean the result, remove vertices, merge by distance to remove doubles:

[image]

- Fill the faces:

[image]